# How to Run VS2017 WebTest from Command Line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mstest, webtest

How can I run MS WebTest from Command Line?  I'm getting DLL not found error.

**1st Step**
I copied everything in \Debug folder to special location to run.
[image]

**2nd Step**
I used VS2017 Command Prompt to run WebTest as described in Tutorials

```
mstest /testContainer:WebTest1.webtest
```

[image]

**Error Result**
But it keeps saying the error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebAndLoadTestProject1

```
<ErrorInfo>
              <Message>Exception in PreWebTest event: Could not load file or assembly 'WebAndLoadTestProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</Message>
              <StackTrace>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
       at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)
       at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTestRuleBase.get_Type()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTestPluginReference.CreateInstance()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.DeclarativeWebTest.OnPreWebTest(PreWebTestEventArgs e)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTest.InvokePreWebTest()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestCaseVariation.Start()</StackTrace>
            </ErrorInfo>
```

It seems to me that the Tests are not running in the given folder.  Looks like, it's running from TestResults/In or TestResults/Out folder where WebAndLoadTestProject.dll does not exist.

I couldn't figure out what I did wrong.  Could you please help me to figure out?

PS.  If I use `mstest /testContainer:WebAndLoadTestProject1.dll`, it says "No tests to execute."

Comment: Why are you passing the ".webtest" file to the `/testContainer`? You should be passing it a `.dll`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx .

Comment: I did try to pass .dll only but, still no luck.  Please see the last line in my question.
I'm following the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms243149(v=vs.100)